# eGalax Touchscreen support, without kernel recompile, raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, kernel, touchscreen

I have been using a custom compiled raspbian OS, with eGalax touchscreen support. The problem is every time there's some upgrade or a major version change in the OS or firmware, I have to recompile the entire OS again, to keep it updated.

Are there any reliable and simpler ways to enable support for eGalax Touchscreens in Raspbian OS, that do not require recompiling the OS.

specs:

Pi model B(No overclocking)

eGalax based touchscreen monitor, connected by HDMI for A/V and USB for TS I/O.

Comment: http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2013/01/17/how-to-get-evtouch-touch-screen-kit-working-in-linux/